# Como leer archivos PDF escritos en Español en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy usando PyPDF2 y Pyttsx3, pero al configurar la voz siempre lo lee en ingles.
Nota: El archivo PDF está escrito en español

```
import PyPDF2
import pyttsx3 

book = open('espanol.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
pages = pdfReader.numPages
page = pdfReader.getPage(6)
text = page.extractText()


speaker = pyttsx3.init()
speaker.setProperty('rate', 175)
voices = speaker.getProperty('voices')
speaker.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
speaker.setProperty('voice', 'spanish')

speaker.say(text)
speaker.runAndWait()eReader(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la linea de `book = open('espanol.pdf','rb')` a `book = open('espanol.pdf','rb', encoding = "latin-1")`.
Por defecto se utiliza `utf-8`, que no soporta caracteres como la ñ o las tildes, con el parametro añadido lo cambias a `latin-1`, que soporta todos los caracteres españoles.